# Ubuntu 12.10 with video and audio out of sync

Tags: sound, video, sync

Movies do not play in sync . Audio and Video not matching. Using the latest VLC to no avail. Ubuntu is fully updated too.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC you can use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> keys to control Audio Delay.